# URL com "app" no lugar de "www"

Tags: url, app, www

Algumas aplicações web, como CRM's (https://app.hubspot.com/ - https://app.moskitcrm.com/), iniciam a url com "app" no lugar de "www".

Gostaria de saber se tratam-se de aplicativos que de alguma forma estão integradas às aplicações que rodam no navegador, e de que forma isso acontece.

Comment: Esta pergunta não é sobre programação, foi simplesmente uma definição da própria empresa, ela simplesmente definiu este prefixo deste domínio para isso, ou seja, eles fizeram uma aplicação web com este domínio.

Comment: Se quiser saber mais sobre o assunto, pesquise sobre, prefixo de domínio ou sub-domínio

Comment: Subdomínios são URLs para diferentes seções no seu site. Eles usam seu domínio principal e um prefixo. Por exemplo, se seu domínio é "www.seudominio.com.br", uma possibilidade de subdomínio, pode ser "suporte.seudominio.com.br".

Comment: Wictor, show de bola! Era exatamente isso que eu precisava saber. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## O que você procura é sobre DNS

Os servidores DNS (Domain Name System, ou sistema de nomes de domínios) são os responsáveis por localizar e traduzir para números IP os endereços dos sites que digitamos. É como uma agenda. Todo o domínio possui um servidor DNS, geralmente fica localizado no painel do próprio host. Para fazer o que você procura é necessário criar um "subdominio" ou seja uma entrada no DNS apontando para o servidor desejado e no servidor ter um HostVirtual associado ao nome criado (app.seudominio.com.br) apontando para a aplicação desejada.